# How to update url path with current tab link clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

My site has a number of pages, where some of the pages use tabbed navigation for sub sections. I have a script that checks the url path, checks to see if it exists in a subNav array and selects a given tab if it exists. However, when I try to navigate to another top level page, the route doesn't change nor does the view without hitting the home link.

How can I modify my routes with React Router (used at the top level) to correctly update the url path and allow navigation between pages/views?

**UPDATE**

I am now able to update the url path, but now when a user clicks on a second tab, it prepends the last clicked tab to the url, instead of clearing the path and using the most currently selected tab.

How can I clear the location set with `useLocation` on each tab click to ensure the latest tab clicked is the only one used in the url path?

So instead of what it should be: `http://localhost:3000/page/tab-1`, it creates `http://localhost:3000/page/tab-1/tab-2` which breaks.

```
        import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
        import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
        import { NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
    
        function TabPanel(props) {
        const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;
      
        return (
          <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            {...other}
          >
            {value === index && (
              <Box p={0} sx={{boxShadow: 2}}>
                <>{children}</>
              </Box>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }
    
    const MyPage = () => {
      const subNav = [
        "tab-1",
        "tab-2",
        "tab-3",
        "tab-4"
      ]
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
      const urlParam = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]
     useEffect(() => {
    subNav.indexOf(urlParam) >- 1 && setValue(subNav.indexOf(urlParam));
  },[subNav, urlParam])
      const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      };
        const { pathname } = useLocation();
        return (
          <div>
              <Tabs value={value} className={classes.appBar} TabIndicatorProps={{
               style: { background: '#5F7D4F', height: "2px" }
             }} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="brand color tabs">
                  {subNav.map((item, i) => 
                    <Tab key={i} value={i} label={`${item.replaceAll('-', ' ')}`} component={NavLink} to={pathname + "/" + item} />
                  )}
              </Tabs>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                Content of tab 1
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                Content of tab 2
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
                Content of tab 3
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
                Content of tab 4
            </TabPanel>
          <PageFooter/>
        </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default MyPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the key was to check the path with:

```
const pathUpdate = item => pathname.split("/")[2] !== undefined ? item : pathname + "/" + item;
```

and then use that function in the tab:

```
<Tab key={i} value={i} label={`${item.replaceAll('-', ' ')}`} component={NavLink} to={pathUpdate(item)} />
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using `Link` and `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` in this file. You'll then want to use `{ BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'` at the top level where your route would be something like... `/tab/:tabIndex`.

Comment: I've updated my code and issue with the current problem